# replace a part of the index route with the show route when clicked

Tags: ember.js

In trying to learn Ember, I'm building a simple blogging app.

I have a Posts Index Handlebars template, which displays a list of posts. When a person clicks on a single post, I'd like the single post to replace the list of posts, rather than the whole template.

How would I go about accomplishing this?

So, for example, --

this is posts.handlebars

```
{{partial '_header'}}
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    {{#each post in controller}}
      {{ render 'post' post}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</div>
```

When a 'post' is clicked, I'd like to replace the code generated by

```
    {{#each post in controller}}
      {{ render 'post' post}}
    {{/each}}
```

with the  single post handlebars template.

--

currently, this is what my routes look like --

```
// For more information see: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/
Blog.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts');
  this.resource('post', { path: '/posts/:post_id' });
});
```

I know we need to use the {{outlet}} in a unique way, and define the routes in a unique way, but am having trouble figuring out that way :*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by defining your route as:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts', function() {

    this.route('index'); //this definition is optional

    this.resource('posts.post', {path: 'post/:post'});
    // or  this.route('post', {path: ':post'});

  });

});
```

Then you must define an **outlet** at the parent post template which will be populated with the posts/index and posts/post templates when entering in each specific route.

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="posts">
     header posts
     <div class="container">
       <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
         {{outlet}}
       </div>
     </div>
  </script>


  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="posts/index">
    {{#each post in controller}}
       {{#link-to 'posts.post' post }}{{post}}{{/link-to}}
    {{/each}}
  </script>


  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="posts/post">
    Hi!!! {{model}}
  </script>
```

A working example is [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/rehey/3/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using the `render` helper to display each blog post, you'll automatically have a controller instance for each post created.  So what we'll do is define a boolean on it, use it to control what's shown and then setup an action to change it whenever the title is clicked, like this:

```
App.PostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    showBody:false,
    actions:{
        toggleBody:function(){
            this.toggleProperty('showBody');
        }
    }
});
```

Now in the `post` template, we revise it to control what's shown, like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#if showBody}}
        <h2 {{action 'toggleBody'}}>{{title}}</h2>
        <p>{{body}}</p>
    {{else}}
        <h2 {{action 'toggleBody'}}>{{title}}</h2>
    {{/if}}
</script>
```

Comment: Hey Nicholas, thanks for the response. This is cool, but what I would love to do is to show the body on the index page, and if a post is clicked, to only show that 1 post. Would that be possible some how? Basically I'd like to have a direct route to a single post.

Comment: Why not just `link-to` the post page then?